# R change number of significant figures in a gt table by replacing values from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, gt

I am trying to create a series of gt tables with values shown to a 3rd sig fig. Because I want to show non numeric characters, the column I want to display is a factor. What's the best way to do this? I thought I could replace the values of a factor column with those from a numeric column, but I am not sure how to go about it. The code below is an example of a larger data set, where I would want to replace all numeric like values in Area1 with corresponding shorter values in Area2

```
Area1 <- as.factor(c(0,0, 0.50659782, "NS"))
Area2 <- c(NA, NA, 0.507, NA)
d <-data.frame(Area1, Area2) %>% gt()
```

Essentially, I want to Area1 column to look like

```
Area1
0
0
0.507
NS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data has mixed types the numbers are already changed to characters/factors. You can use regex approach to keep data only till 3 decimal places.

```
library(gt)
Area1 <- as.factor(c(0,0, 0.50659782, "NS"))
Area2 <- c(NA, NA, 0.507, NA)
d <-data.frame(Area1, Area2) 
d$Area1 <- ifelse(is.na(d$Area2), as.character(d$Area1), d$Area2)
d <- d[-2]
gt(d)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, but the solution you propose replaces values across all columns, which there are several in my original data set. I need something that will target only Area1 column, across several rows

Comment: It also does not round up or down values

Comment: You cannot round the values because those are not numbers but factors. Check `class(d$Area1)`. Instead of `lapply` use `d$Area1 <- sub('(.*\\..{3}).*', '\\1', d$Area1)` to target only `Area1`.

Comment: yes I understand that I can't round factors, that is why I wanted to try replacing those values with corresponding Area2 values

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I will keep this question open, as I would still like to find a solution with replacement of values from Area2

Comment: In my answer I am replacing values from `Area2` in `Area1`. check the `ifelse` code.

Comment: ok, I see it now. Thanks. I am still unsure of the exact meaning in `sub('(.*\\..{3}).*', '\\1', d$Area1)`. What does ''(.*\\..{3}).*'' mean?

Comment: That selects numbers till 3 decimal places. Although I have removed that code now.